# Giving input_file_path argument to glue from Glue console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, etl, aws-glue

I want to pass an s3 filename as an input_file_path which I want to execute job from Glue console.Is their any way to give input_file_path argument from AWS Glue console?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create job parameter via Glue Console (UI), you have to first define the argument in the job:

- unfold the *Script libraries and job parameters* sections
  [image]
- enter your parameter:
  [image]
- Read it in your code (Scala example):

  ```
  def main(sysArgs: Array[String]) {
    val args = GlueArgParser.getResolvedOptions(sysArgs, Array("input_file_path"))
    print(s"Input path: ${args("input_file_path")}")
  }
  ```
- Read it in your code (Python):

  ```
  import sys

  args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['input_file_path'])
  print(args['input_file_path'])
  ```